# Retrieve VARRAY element type using TYPE attribute

Tags: oracle, plsql

i want to retrieve type of elements varray stores through type attribute or ANY work around.

for example our type is defined like this

```
CREATE TYPE "READINGS" AS VARRAY (200) OF NUMBER(21, 6);
```

(readings is varray with elements of type `number(21,6)`)

`READINGS` is a column in a table `INTERVALS`. `INTERVALS` is a central table and we have batch processes on `INTERVALS` which execute sql store procedures. In store procedure we have hard coded variable declarations mapping to the `READING` VArray type element type which is `NUMBER(21, 6)` for example the store procedure has variable declarations like

```
CONSUMPTION NUMBER(21, 6);
```

whenever Varray definition is changed or varray is dropped and recreated with different size and precision, ex instead on `number(21,6)` is changed to `number(25,9)` we need to change our variable declarations in all batch process store procedures.
All i am looking for is making CONSUMPTION variable declaration, refer to element type of VArray. I want something like this

```
CONSUMPTION INTERVALS.READINGS.COLUMN_TYPE%TYPE;
```

(i want some thing like this, refer to the type of elements stored by varray)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you creating a table with a `VARRAY` column in the first place? It would generally make far more sense to create a separate table for `READINGS` with a foreign key that lets you relate the rows back to the `INTERVALS` table. You could then easily enough declare columns of type `READINGS.COLUMN_NAME%TYPE`.

Collections are wildly useful in PL/SQL. I've never seen a case where they improved on a standard normalized approach to data modeling. I have seen multiple cases where incorporating collections into your data model ends up making your data model harder to work with and your code harder to write and maintain.

If you don't want to fix the data model, you can

- Declare a `SUBTYPE` or a packaged variable of type `NUMBER(21, 6)` that you use as the type for your variable declarations.  You'll have to change this definition if and when you change the declaration of the `VARRAY` type.
- Create an object type with a single attribute (a `NUMBER(21,6)`) and define the `VARRAY` based on that object type.  Then you can declare instances of the object type in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a required solution, but you can get string of type definition for further using it in dynamic SQL

```
SELECT 
   regexp_substr(text, 'VARRAY.*?OF\s+(.+?)(;|\s)*$', 1, 1, 'i', 1) 
FROM user_source 
WHERE name = 'READINGS'
```